# Overriding cellForRowAtIndexPath in UITableViewController subclass returns error: does not override any method from superclass

Tags: ios, swift, class, inheritance, overriding

Here is the code for my class

```
import UIKit

class VideoSearchController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var searchResults: NSDictionary = [:]

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    // Can't override
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SearchTableCell

        cell.videoTitle.text = "This is the title"
        cell.viewCount.text = "1,234,567"
        cell.channelName.text = "benlvn"
        let url = URL(string: "https://i.redd.it/78r3ttko3nnz.jpg")
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
        cell.thumbnail.image = UIImage(data: data!)

        return cell
    }

    // Can't override
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // Override works
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return searchResults.count
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        // TODO
    }

    func searchBarIsEmpty() -> Bool {
        // Returns true if the text is empty or nil
        return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
    }

}
```

Even though VideoSearchController inherits from UITableViewController, it won't let me override cellForrowAtIndexPath or numberOfSectionsInTableView because those methods don't exist in the superclass.  However, it does let me override numberOfRowsInSection.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: You are attempting to override the old Swift 2 API.

Answer (score 2):

The declarations are:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

And

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
```